# System.Windows.Input.Key is not working in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, key

I am trying to use the Keyboard.isKeyDown and Keyboard.isKeyUp functions from System.Windows.Input, in c#.

The functions appear to be working but it doesn't allow me to use the Key from System.Windows.Input.Key, so I can't call these functions.

How can I fix this?

**this is my code:**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace rubicksTimer
{
    
    public class Timer
    {

        public static double SolveTimer ()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            while (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.Space))
            {
                //empty loop
            }
            
            while (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Space))
            {
                //empty loop
            }
            
            sw.Start();

            while (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.Space))
            {
                //empty loop
            }

            sw.Stop();

            return (double) (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) / 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code you've provided, it's not showing how you're calling any of this. Can you explain in detail as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to make a timer that will start when I release the space bar, and stop when I press it again

Comment: I understand, how are you calling this code?

Comment: (I'm not sure I understood the question) I am calling it In a Main Class, in the following way: double time = Timer.SolveTimer();

Answer (score 0):

Just use KeyDown and KeyUp events for e.Key == Key.Space

Comment: I didn't understand this answer. Can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Your Window has KeyDown and KeyUp events that you can handle your commands there. It is a better way to handle it there instead of using while() loops.

Comment: But how does this solve my issue of not being able to use System.Windows.Input.Key?

Comment: Explain 'not being able to use System.Windows.Input.Key'
I just used it above e.Key == Key.Space

Comment: Just register to these events and use in KeyDown if (e.Key == Key.Space) sw.Start()
and on KeyUp event if (e.Key == Key.Space) sw.Stop();

Comment: The problem I have is that when I write Key.Space, the code says it doesn't know what Key is.

Comment: ok next time please make your question more clear. Do you use winforms or wpf? because that's for wpf

Comment: From what I understand, I am using wpf